# How to get Likes and share count and get mail id's from whose like my posts in facebook using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have used Facebook PHP SDK

```
include('src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',   // Facebook App ID
'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',  // Facebook App Secret
'cookie' => true,
));
$data = getData("MyCodingTricks");
$likes = $data['likes'];
echo "Facebook Likes: ".$likes;
function getData($username){
$access_token = 'Here i have placed secret code'; //Replace it with your Access Token
 $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$username."?access_token=".$access_token),true);
return $json;
}
```

i am in new for this concepts i have tried above code, and i got error like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook
>   needs the CURL PHP extension.' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\fb_php5.3\src\base_facebook.php:19 Stack
>   trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\fb_php5.3\src\facebook.php(18):
>   require_once() #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\fb_php5.3\example2.php(5):
>   include('D:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\fb_php5.3\src\base_facebook.php on line 19

after that I have to enable curl extension form php.ini file from xampp/php/php.ini

but same error display again and **i need count value from likes and shares on my facebook each posts and news feeds, and i need to get email id from whose like my post and share my post..**

note: my php version is 5.3.4 and i have appid and secret and my API version is 2.7

my question is my above need is possible? can i get mail id from whose like my post? and facebook SDK only enough for my needs? how to use facebook SDK for reach my needs?

Comment: if the error still comes up, i assume you did not install the curl extension correctly

Comment: and no, of coures you can´t get the mail of people who liked your post. what would you even do with their email without their explicit permission? you would not even be able to store it.

Comment: you need to activate `php_curl` and probably `php_openssl` in your `php.ini` file in the `apache\bin` folder

Comment: i have changed `;extension=php_curl.dll` as `extension=php_curl.dll` this is correct

Comment: can i get username from whose likes instead of mail id

Comment: how to get all posts from till now and can i get likes count and share counts from each posts? is it possible

Comment: can i know reason about we can't get email id?

Comment: I would hope its private. Otherwise we would all be getting spam email from you.... Right

Comment: You can not get username or email.

Comment: WizKid@ is that only reason for Privacy? or Is there any other reason?